# A specific way of asking for a meeting?

Tags: idioms, formality

Can one say "... if you(I) could see me(you) on Friday..." when requesting a meeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible correct sentences for this include, but are not limited to:

- *If you could see me on Friday....* (requires something after, e.g. “that would be great”
- *Could you see me on Friday?*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thank you. So, can it be constructed as "I was wondering if you could see me on Friday for an hour?"

Comment: That sentence works fine :)